# Как добавить в приложение уже заполненную базу?

Tags: android, sqlite

Есть приложение, в нем есть список чего-то на 200 итемов.

Как мне поставлять приложение с уже заполненной базой ?
т.е. чтобы после установки приложения этот список заполнился из базы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Схематично:

1. В `assets` кладете Вашу БД
2. Создаете БД в приложении (стандартно `SQLiteOpenHelper`)
3. Копируете при первом запуске БД из assets в БД приложения.
4. Работаете с заполненной БД.
5. После очистки данных приложения пользователем повторить п.3

Comment: Спасибо за отклик. Я вот думаю правильно ли вообще использовать такую БД. Цель: есть игра, есть список усовершенствований, каждое усовершенствование или несколько становится доступно при достижении определенного уровня. Я думаю сделать таблицу, в которой будут поля уровень и дальше уже описание достижения, что оно дает и тд.